# How to setup a development environment for java in unix for each of the team member

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, docker, quartz-scheduler

Earlier I worked on Ruby on Rails.
We, all the developers used to pull the latest image from docker.
Once the docker is up and running, we were able to do development locally.
Once the code changes are done, we used to push to our respective git branch and once its merged, we used to deploy to production.
The app was hosted on Heroku.

(As you can see all the developers used to work on their own local copy. Postgress database configuration and dummy data was already set for local)

Now as a new startup, we are using java, spring, hibernate, quartz.

We want to have similar architecture set up as I discussed in the beginning.

I was looking for solution in google. Many authors and articles suggested to use jenkins and github but none of the articles mentioned a complete dev environment setup process sothat each developer can work independently.

Main goal-

1. **Each developer must get his/her own local copy and work on it(Java)**
2. **Pre configured database locally**
3. **Dump dummy data**
4. **Deployment process** (what is the best hosting service for java app like heroku for rails)

Ultimate Goal:-
A new joinee comes runs a shell script and the entire development environment is set for him and he can start contributing to the project on the same day itself.

**Which database should be used with java considering it is a startup, database's performance and cost and reliablity with Java?**(Mysql or posstgresql or any other)

**Which OS should be used again considering it is a startup, database's performance and cost and reliablity with Java?**(Ubuntu or Windows, Current we are on Ubuntu)

**What is the best solution(step by step) for setting up entire independent dev environment for each developer while using java,spring,hibernate, quartz technologies**?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer what we did in a previous startup I've worked at. Worked well for us, maybe there other better alternatives.

- Postgres is a good db.
- We used Centos for production so Fedora locally, so it will be the same linux family. Anyway I don't see any reason to use Windows for development.
- You can use hibernate to create the db schema and tables from your java pojo entities.
- We had scripts which pre-populate certain tables with desired values. E.g. users table.
- All scripts were integrated to run by executing maven commands.
- We used scripts to create the dev env, with configuration of local apache httpd proxy and many other things. It can be quite complicated.
- We used Artifactory to hold and cache the current and previous maven artifacts, both of our product and our maven dependencies.
- As for Quartz, it shouldn't be a problem. Notice that there is an integration of Spring with Quartz, use it.
- We used local Gitlab as our repo.
- We used local hosted Jenkins for our CI.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the response but can you please elaborate the part We used scripts to create the dev env, with configuration of local apache httpd proxy and many other things. It can be quite complicated. Any link for detailed step or you can give a deep insight from your end

and

how to use  Artifactory to hold and cache the current and previous maven artifacts, both of our product and our maven dependencies.(I am going through the official doc of Artifactory)

Comment: About the scripts - it did many things but basically the all the scripts which we used to install the web app on a server(on a clean env), also installed it on our own dev machines. 
Now I also recall that at some point we started using chef and then the cookbooks we used to install a new server could also install a new environment(there are many already-made recopies of chef which you can use). There are very few differences between the working env and the prod env.
But maybe docker can still make it more easy.

Comment: As for Artifactory(and also somewhat for the scripts), I can't really dive into more details here. But there should be plenty of tutorials on the web

Comment: Hi, went through many articles. Now We are going to build our dev env using Docker, Maven, Jenkin.
doubt: If we use docker, then we need not any extra container/server(like tomcat or glassfix) right?

Comment: Hi, I don't any reason that docker will influence using/not using tomcat etc. But I didn't use docker with Java so maybe there is something I'm not aware of. 
Also, please consider using openjdk instead of Oracle JDK. According to [this](http://blog.takipi.com/running-java-on-docker-youre-breaking-the-law/) using Oracle JDK with docker may be problematic, and anyway many consider openjdk as better than Oracle JDK.